# Run PS commands every time a file is added to a folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to create a script which main task is to execute a few PS commands every time a file is added to a folder. 
I've tied using "do" which will enter the program in a loop. But when i add a file into the folder the commands are executed only once and then i am getting errors for the newly added files. Below is a sample of my code
 Do you have any idea how can i do this?
Thanks in advance!

```
do{
Dir *.txt | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "eml")}
Invoke-Item C:\Users\*.eml
Remove-Item C:\Users\*.eml
} until ("condition that is never met")
```

Comment: Be more specific: what you mean by 'adding a file to a directory'? Do you mean that the number of files will grow? Or the total number of files does not need to grow (just swapping a file for another one is 'adding')? Also: is changing of file name 'adding'? Is changing file content 'adding'?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `FileSystemWatcher` together with 
[Register-ObjectEvent](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135244) to get notified when a file is added:

```
$folder = 'c:\test'
$filter = '*.txt'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ IncludeSubdirectories = $true}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    # A file has been added, run your ps commands here. e. g.
    write-host $path
}
```

To unregister the event, use:

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
```